# in virtual env, with centos and pip installed, I can't run a pip freeze

Tags: python-2.7, centos, pip

I have a program where I dearly need the dependency list, but `pip freeze` isn't working.  I am running CentOS 7 and Python 2.7.5

The program runs on Python 2.4 (which I am doing as an alias in another terminal, yes, I did try the `pip freeze` from that terminal) and fortran95.  I definitely have pip installed.  I tried upgrading the Python2.7, but it says it is fine.

The the error from pip is as follows.

```
[root@localhost rotate6]# pip freeze

Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main status = self.run(options, args)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/freeze.py", line 85, in run
    for line in freeze(**freeze_kwargs):

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/operations/freeze.py", line 47, in freeze
    dependency_links

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 264, in from_dist
    req = dist.as_requirement()

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2562, in as_requirement
    return Requirement.parse(spec)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2833, in parse
    req, = parse_requirements(s)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2781, in parse_requirements
    yield Requirement(line)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2790, in __init__
    raise RequirementParseError(str(e))

RequirementParseError: Invalid requirement, parse error at "'-ipap11h'"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue.  See https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3764

The advice there is to try downgrading your version of `pip` to one that is less strict (some people find 8.1.0 works), or to uninstall the offending package, which appears to be `_ipap11helper`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.  Next time, I'll know to focus more on the "parse error" part of the message.

Comment: @MichelleWhalenKaiser You're welcome.  If that resolves your problem, don't forget to accept the answer...